# What should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

We, like all other sites, have a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/quantum-computing). However, currently it has the rather boring name of "Quantum Computing".

Most other sites have a room with a more intresting name: The Nineteenth Byte for Code Golf, The Sphinx's Lair for Puzzling, The Bridge for Arqade, etc.

What are your suggestions for a better chat room name?

Comment: The h Bar is already taken by Physics.

Comment: It seems that there is a bit of a consensus =)

Comment: Thanks to our new room owner, Blue, our chat room has been renamed to "The Classical Channel"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### (The) Classical channel

In quantum computing, a classical channel is a means of transferring classical information.
The chatroom is a classical channel.

Imagine all the ridiculous puns that will be enjoyed...

Comment: I like this. But perhaps modify it a bit to "**The Classical Channel**".

Comment: I second @Blue's proposal

Comment: I cannot think of a single pun.

Comment: @KenSharp Clearly, your _classical_ methods are insufficient. Try Quantum ;)

Comment: :( but quantum mechanics is in a way the _opposite_ of classical.

Answer (score 5):

**The Entanglement**

Because this is at the heart of quantum computing.

Comment: Or Human Entanglement because the chatroom connects humans ...

Answer (score 4):

## Schrödinger's Chat

A pun on [Schrödinger's Cat](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shrodinger_cat_paradox). It has more to do with Quantum Mechanics in general than just Quantum Computing, but I wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: I -1'ed this proposal and want to explain my reasoning – As you said yourself, this is more about *Quantum* rather than *Computing*, and we seem to [ban such *questions*](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing). Having this name *might* therefore confuse some, so I think we should choose something more specific to *quantum computing* (this one fist Physics.SE too, for example). Though I have to agree that the pun is great :)

Comment: Oh my, you used my name, or rather some mispronounced form of it, without my permission!! That's straight-away a copyright infringement...

Answer (score 1):

Really, really bad one, but: **Controlled-HAT**: controlled-NOT or CNOT, or, in this case, CHAT...

Comment: I like the idea of this, if not the exact example. Some kind of pun on quantum gates would be neat.

Answer (score 1):

### Quantum channel

A quantum channel is a means of transferring quantum information, i.e. a quantum bit register.
In the case of the chat room, the "quantum channel" refers to the idea that each SE site is a channel for a specific topic, this one being quantum computation.

Answer (score 0):

QuChat. (Or maybe QChat)

Like bit $\rightarrow$ qubit, chat $\rightarrow$QuChat

It also has QC<sub>hat</sub> in it.

Comment: Maybe QuaC?????

Comment: @VladSpirin QuaC is also great. Perhaps put it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score -1):

## The Unobservatory

Because this site is about research where you can't observe what you're studying (the qubits) without ruining their state.

Answer (score -2):

```
<Qu|Co|De>
```

I don't know how this will go, but, as mentioned in the above name, **Qu.Co.De.** means **Quantum Computing Department**.

Comment: It is my opinion that if a room name is best rendered using Latex it's not a great room name.

Comment: @Pavel I used Latex only to increase the size of my title. Other than that, the Latex has no use. I am removing it if it creates any miscommunication.

Comment: I meant that more generally, that symbols in a room name aren't a good thing.