# Resources for learning Quantum Computing

Tags: discussion

At least in my opinion, Quantum Computing is an awesome area of development for computing. However, it is also a daunting field (as far as I know, you have to know quite a bit of physics to be able to do quantum computing, as well as of course computer science and programming). I would like to start a list of resources for quantum computing like the list on [resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-learning-chemistry), or [resources for learning Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese). 
That way [resource questions](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed) can also be redirected to this area.

Comment: Also, I'm new here. Please edit or comment on my post if you believe it needs clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We welcome questions like this on the main site! However, there is a proper way to ask them. See our [resource request policy](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed/31#31).

In summary:

> Resource recommendations must ask for descriptive answers. It's not enough to ask for a list of books that cover topic X — a simple Amazon search can provide that.
>
> Instead, you should ask for recommendations, which specify:
>
> - What the book covers
> - How it covers it — is it rigorous? Intuitive? How is the writer's style?
> - What are the prerequisites? and similar questions.

For a question like you're suggesting, you probably are asking for intuitive resources with minimal prerequisites that cover the basics of the theory of quantum computing, or maybe you're asking for a list of prerequisites for beginners, and resources for those prerequisites.

Also, these questions should **not** be community wiki.

---

I welcome comments from the community and the other mods on this issue.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if we could have an answer here like Chemistry, the language sites, etc. listing valuable textbooks, online resources, etc.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder as we collect resource-request questions, you can find them all by tag. As we get more and have some definitive resource questions, we can create a meta post to help guide users to them. However, at this point, we don't really have any resource questions, so it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Accepted